# Missing permissions: storage.objects.update when trying to export Model from AI Platform (Google Cloud)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I trained a model on Google Cloud AI Platform (Unified). I have used it on deploy (endpoint) already but I need to export it to Cloud Storage, but I'm receiving "Missing permission" on a project that I'm the Owner

I'm using User account via Web Console, my role is Owner. The missing permission is "storage.objects.update"

[image: The error message]

Comment: Edit your question with details. 1) Are you using  User Credentials or a Service Account? 2) What roles are assigned to the credentials? 3) What is the missing permission? 4) Show your code that is setting up authorization. 5) Most likely you are not using the credentials you think you are. Double check everything.

Comment: @JohnHanley Added some info. (I'm not trying to export via code)

Comment: As I commented you are not using the credentials you think you are. Enable a Cloud Storage role to the Service Agent https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/general/access-control#service-agents